# Efficient way to find index of elements in a large list of integers starting with max to min elements

Tags: python, sorting

I have a large list of *integers unsorted*, numbers might be duplicated. I would like to create another list which is a list of sub-lists of indexes from the first list starting with max element to min, in decreasing order. 
For example, if I have a list like this:

```
list = [4, 1, 4, 8, 5, 13, 2, 4, 3, 7, 14, 4, 4, 9, 12, 1, 6, 14, 10, 8, 6, 4, 11, 1, 2, 11, 3, 9]
```

The output should be:

```
indexList = [[10, 17], [5], [14], [22, 25], [18], [13, 27], [3, 19], [9], [16, 20], [4], [0, 2, 7, 11, 12, 21], [8, 26], [6, 24], [1, 15, 23]]
```

where, `[10, 17]` is the index of where '`14`' is present and so on...

Shared my code below. Profiling it using cProfile for a list of around 9000 elements takes around ~6 seconds.

```
def indexList(list):
    # List with sorted elements
    sortedList = sorted(list, reverse = True)

    seen = set()
    uSortedList = [x for x in sortedList if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]

    indexList = []
    for e in uSortedList:
        indexList.append([i for i, j in enumerate(list) if j == e])

    return indexList
```

Comment: Need code in python.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, apologize if my question is not clearly asked, asking a question for the first time and am learning. thanks.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? Knowing that will allow me to make further performance improvements.

Comment: @Learning Nice, thanks for updating the question and welcome to SO. :-)

Comment: I think it is a good question. It is more related to data structures than to Python.

Comment: @pzp, I am using python 2.7.10

Comment: Any interest in @Learning [numpy](http://www.numpy.org)? For long lists (10k), this is about 4 times faster than @pzp's code: `np.split(np.argsort(L), np.cumsum(np.bincount(L)))[::-1]` (Less efficient of an algorithm, but implemented in C by folks smarter than I.)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
def get_list_indices(ls):
    indices = {}
    for n, i in enumerate(ls):
        try:
            indices[i].append(n)
        except KeyError:
            indices[i] = [n]
    return [i[1] for i in sorted(indices.items(), reverse=True)]

test_list = [4, 1, 4, 8, 5, 13, 2, 4, 3, 7, 14, 4, 4, 9, 12, 1, 6, 14, 10, 8, 6, 4, 11, 1, 2, 11, 3, 9]
print(get_list_indices(test_list))
```

Based on some very basic testing, it is about twice as fast as the code you posted.

Comment: This is exactly what I would do. Writing the indices in a dictionary values and then printing them sorted by the keys. The only change I'd do is related to the code and I'm not sure if is better - instead of expecting an error, I would check `if i not in indices -> then indices[i] = []`

Comment: You can use `indices.setdefault(i, []).append(n)` to avoid the try-except, and  instead of `indices.items()` we can simply use `indices`.

Comment: @pzp, tested your code and yes its around twice faster than mine, thanks,  can this be improved further?

Comment: @SomethingSomething In Python it is better to use a ``try... except...`` than an if statement. This is related to the concept of [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission) vs. [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) (Look Before You Leap), which you can find out more about in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).

Comment: I think it's the best possible solution. It iterates your list only once, sorts the keys in O(nlogn) and prints them according to the order. I can't think about anything faster. Your input must be very very large if the speed does not satisfy you

Comment: @pzp, according to the example in your link, I don't think my solution is slower. To get to the exception, it also has to first look for the key in the dictionary. Anyway, it's nice to know another coding style

Comment: @SomethingSomething yes, my input list is quite large, but the solution is working within the time for now.

Comment: @SomethingSomething But it only has to catch the exception if the item does not exist (in which case it's "wasting" a lookup), but if it already does it just goes on doing its business. LBYL requires a "wasted" lookup regardless of whether or not the element is already in the dictionary. When working with a large list with a lot of duplicates, as the OP is, it can save quite a bit of lookups. In addition (I don't know if the link I gave you discussed this), EAFP also helps to prevent racetime conditions and is generally considered more Pythonic.